# Sphinx indexer does not fetch data when MySQL transaction is used

Tags: mysql, transactions, laravel-5.1, sphinx, indexer

please help me with running phpunit tests that check module with sphinx search engine.

To search in that module I use two sphinx indexes `docs` and `docsdelta`. After new data are appear in the DB, I do following:

```
exec("indexer docsdelta --rotate");
exec("indexer --merge docs docsdelta --rotate");
```

It works well on my website and I am able to add new document through the web interface and it appears in the search.

On the same time when I run phpunit test and it creates new document "on fly",

```
exec("indexer docsdelta --rotate");
```

does not fetch any new data. My phpunit tests use transactions to rollback the database to the previous state and I notice, that indexer works properly in case if I switch off transactions. Additionally I am able to see new data in the DB, just before and after running `indexer`. Maybe I missed something but I do not understand why transaction has an influence on indexer.

Is it some way to use `indexer docdelta` together with MySQL transaction?

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make changes you make inside the transaction visible outside, i.e. to indexer you need to change isolation level of the indexer's SELECT queries. You can do it like this:

`sql_query_pre = SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`

You can read more about mysql isolation levels here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html